# splitting data in a column into multiple columns in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help in splitting the below data into a table. I need to do that in snowflake. What would be the SQL for splitting this data format into multiple columns in the form of a table?

I just can't figure out how to do it.

data:

{"{"Locale": "England", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "9250", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "Northern Ireland", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "9250", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "Scotland", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "9250", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "Wales", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "9250", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "Channel Islands", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "9250", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "Republic of Ireland", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "9250", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "EU", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "17500", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}","{"Locale": "International", "CourseId": "882d3d41-ab18-a87d-0b10-7d2ee0af95cf", "Currency": "GBP", "FeeState": "Provisional", "CourseFees": "17500", "AcademicYear": "2023", "CourseOptionId": "8391ff2c-8a16-4b5b-a1f4-2352fcf79b96", "FeeDurationPeriod": "Year 1"}"}

Table:

[image: Partial Table created from the above data]

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all information directly to your question. What have you tried and what issue are you having?

Comment: Also, that not valid JSON

Comment: @JamesZ that was a partial JSON. now I have shared the complete JSON.

Comment: @NickW I can't seem to figure out how to do it. some formulas that I have in mind that could do it are: parse_json. But they are also not working. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Valid JSON cannot start with `{"{"Locale":`. You can validate it for example here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @JamesZ kindly consider it as a data instead of a JSON, and needed to be converted into a table. I have modified the above question as well, and removed all mention of 
 a JSON. Thanks

Comment: If this is not valid JSON then you'd need to manually parse the data yourself which would probably require a Stored Proc - therefore I would strongly suggest that you make your data valid  JSON